# What is the best source to read angular ?

Tags: angularjs

I am a Beginer in Angular Js. I love to read in paperback. I checked out http://www.amazon.in/AngularJS-Brad-Green/dp/1449344852 , not sure about it.

Can Anyone give me a suggestion?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: This is a question with subjective answers and is thus not really suitable for StackOverflow. Instead, try posting in the AngularJS IRC channel or on the mailing list.

Comment: 1. This is an [**off-topic**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - "4. Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book**, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are **off-topic for Stack Overflow**."
2. Take a look at [Mastering Web Application Development with AngularJS by Pawel Kozlowski](http://www.amazon.com/Mastering-Web-Application-Development-AngularJS/dp/1782161821), really nice book

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As GregL said , this question is not suitable for stackoverflow. Though few suggestions, the book which reviewing currently is good source. You can even check out : ng-book-The-Complete-Book-AngularJS  which is written by [AriLerner](https://www.linkedin.com/in/arilerner).

Also if you are not very strict about paperback , then you can check out [EggHead](https://egghead.io/) , these guys are doing good job , not too boring since they have very short videos.

I suggest you to post the same question in some [AngularJS IRC](http://irc.lc/ircnet/angularjs/irctc@@@) Channel for better source.